# Folder Permissions of Wordpress in a Windows Server

Tags: windows, wordpress, iis

I'm installing a Wordpress blog (www.mydomain.com/blog) on Windows servers (yes, yes,I know...) and I'm having some trouble understanding the folder permissions and I would like to be very clear about who-is-who and who I give permissions to do what. In a sense, I need to "translate" the Linux CHMOD numbers to my windows server installation.

Here goes:
In a Linux server I can select permissions for the wp-admin folder (say) like so:

```
             Read   Write   Execute CHMOD
Owner           4         2        1    = 7
Group           4                  1    = 5
Public          4                  1    = 5
```

In Plesk I follow domains - mydomain.com - File Manager- wp-admin (lock symbol) - Advanced. I have this list:

```
Users                   Inherited from      Apply to
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrators              ...com\httpdocs\    This folder, subfolders and files
SYSTEM                  ...com\httpdocs\    This folder, subfolders and files
Plesk IIS User (IUSR_oneuser)       ...com\httpdocs\    This folder and subfolders
Plesk IIS User (IUSR_oneuser)       ...com\httpdocs\    Files only
Plesk IIS WP User (IWAM_plesk(default)) ...com\httpdocs\    This folder and subfolders
Plesk IIS WP User (IWAM_plesk(default)) ...com\httpdocs\    Files only
Plesk FTP User (anotheruser)        ...com\httpdocs\    This folder and subfolders
Plesk FTP User (anotheruser)        ...com\httpdocs\    Files only
Plesk Domain User (oneuser)
```

(oneuser and anotheruser are two FTP accounts to access the site)

When I click on each item, the permission list activates allowing...

```
Full Control
Read Control
Write Control
Execute Control
Traverse Folder / Execute File
List Folder / Read Data
Create Files / Write Data
Create Folders / Append Data
Delete subfolders and Files
Delete
Change Permissions
Take Ownership
```

So, I have Read, Write and Execute but I guess that I would also need "Create Files" If I need to upload data (images/videos) onto my blog.

My question (as a Linux CHMOD translation) is:

- Who is the "owner"? The administrator? The SYSTEM?
- Who is "group"?
- Who is "public"?

For example, I am told that wp-admin should be CHMOD 755 and wp-admin/index.php CHMOD 644. Which of the above items (type of user) do I click and what permissions do I give each one to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

network service 
and 
iusr (anonymous access public grp)
just set use the same permissions moving them based on the words and u will have it 
'modify' is the write u need for the network service